# Omega 3 and node--[content type].tpl.php not detected. How to apply custom tpl files?

Tags: theming

We are trying to format the layout for a specific node type and from what I can gather from the net the node--[content type].tpl.php file is the place to do that. We have created the file and placed it in the sub theme directory. After a "drush cc all" the tpl file is still not being applied to output.

Is this the correct way to change the layout of a content type, where their are fields that need theming? Should we just use filed override function instead? Using delta will not work as we want to format the display of the node fields in a particular way and not just move it whole sale to a new region.

I have also seen reference to editing the region--content.tpl.php file but its not the region we want to edit, just the way the node is displayed.

thanks

Comment: Can you confirm the exact machine name of your content type and the exact filename you are using?

Comment: Also take a look at http://drupal.org/node/223440 and http://drupal.org/node/1089656.  You likely have the .tpl.php file misnamed; I don't think this is an Omega problem.

Comment: +MPD thanks! I see the machine name is article_page and not just article. So the name of the tpl file should be node--article_page.tpl.php.

Comment: That should work.